# avrdude error - stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0xff

Tags: arduino, avr, programmer, attiny, avrdude

I am using my Arduino Uno as a programmer to program my ATtiny85. I uploaded the ArduinoISP sketch to my Uno. I double checked my wiring, did some googling, but I still can't figure out why I get this error:

`avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0xff`

when I run this command:

`sudo avrdude -p t85 -c avrisp -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 9600 -U flash:w:src.hex`

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: start by changing `avrisp` to `arduino`.

Comment: @jippie I already tried that, nothing different happened...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have requested 9600 baud serial communication, which is probably not correct for your ISP sketch.

I believe by default that it is now 19200, but you can tell for sure by finding the initialization line in your ISP sketch, such as

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);
```

The -b parameter to avrdude specifies the baud rate for communication with the programmer.

In contrast -B paramater specifies the speed of the actual programming, though I'm not entirely convinced that this is honored when using the ISP sketch.

Answer (score 2):

By default, an Arduino Uno automatically resets itself whenever the host computer opens its serial port. After that, the boot loader waits for a few seconds to see whether there is any serial traffic intended for it, and that disrupts the communication sent by avrdude.

You’ll have to disable this auto-reset by connecting a 10µF capacitor between the RESET and GND pins (`-` going to GND, of course).

Comment: I already had that a 10µF capacitor between the RESET and GND pins, thanks though...